# How do I know if an object can be duplicated?

Tags: ruby

I'm implementing the `to_a` method of a class, and I want all objects that *can* be duplicated (like `String`) to be duplicated, while leaving other types (like `Symbol` and `Integer`) alone. First I thought that was simple:

```
if object.respond_to? :dup
  object.dup
else
  object
end
```

Turns out, all objects respond to `:dup`, but integers and symbols raise a type error. I could do this:

```
begin
  object.dup
rescue TypeError
  object
end
```

But I want to avoid using exceptions for control flow.

---

Is there any way to check if an object can be duplicated without relying on exceptions?

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0

Comment: @Surya: Added it to the question, sorry

Comment: @Surya: Yes, `#respond_to?` returns `true` for *all* objects. That's the problem. `#dup` raises a type error on integers and symbols.

Comment: I'm sure you've come across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4414835/877472) already. That person had the same idea. I suppose you could create a helper, but that'll still use exception handling anyways.

Comment: I should have scrolled [further down](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17562437/877472). Seems like Rails (specifically the [ActiveSupport gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport)), adds a method [`duplicable?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable_rb.html) method. Is it feasible to add that gem?

Comment: @PaulRichter it seems that Rails hard coded that. http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable_rb.html @Hubro you can ask user of your class/module to implement 2/3 methods: `duplicable?` and `dup`/`clone` (already defined).

Comment: @DarekNędza You mean that they've simply hard coded `true` and `false` in the method for certain classes? Yeah, just noticed that too. Not as fancy as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Not able to give you a good reply, but this is an example of where I would try to ask the ruby core team to add the functionality (unless someone else finds a simple way to find out whether an object can be duplicated or not).

This should not be a big addition, considering that all objects save for BasicObject inherit from class Object anyway.

So perhaps this is a case where .duplicable? can be added right to the core.

bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't frozen `obj` then (in Ruby 2 anyway) I believe `obj.frozen?` is `true` if and only if `obj` is not dupable, which I believe is `true` if and only if `obj` is immutable; e.g.:

```
1.frozen?     #=> true
:a.frozen?    #=> true
'cat'.frozen? #=> false
```

Another way to check if `obj` is dupable is (even if `obj` has been frozen) is, I think, is to see if `obj.class.respond_to? :new` is `true`:

```
1.class.respond_to? :new     #=> false
:a.class.respond_to? :new    #=> false
'cat'.class.respond_to? :new #=> true
```

I invite readers to "prove" these conjectures, or disprove them (e.g., with  counterexamples).